# Extracting table data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

Having a little trouble using BeautifulSoup to extract data (zip code and population). Any help appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np    
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

pop_source = requests.get("https://www.zip-codes.com/city/tx-austin.asp").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(pop_source, 'html5lib')    
zip_pop_table = soup.find('table',class_='statTable')    

austin_pop = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Zip Code','Population'])    

for row in zip_pop_table.find_all('tr'):    
    cols = row.find_all('td')
```

Now I'm stuck. Don't really know how to pull the data in the columns I want and append it to the columns I made in the empty dataframe.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop over your `cols`, and dump that into your `austin_pop` dataframe.

So I did that by making a list of the data from the `cols` using list comprehension:

```
row_list = [ data.text for data in cols ]
```

List comprehension equivalent to a `for` loop. You can use either.:

```
row_list = []
for data in cols:
    rows_list.append(data.text)
```

Created a single row, kept the 2 columns you wanted, and then dumped that in to `austin_pop`:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame([row_list], columns = ['Zip Code','type','county','Population', 'area_codes'])
temp_df = temp_df[['Zip Code', 'Population']]
austin_pop = austin_pop.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Full Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.zip-codes.com/city/tx-austin.asp"
pop_source = requests.get("https://www.zip-codes.com/city/tx-austin.asp").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(pop_source, 'html5lib')
zip_pop_table = soup.find('table',class_='statTable')

austin_pop = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Zip Code','Population'])

for row in zip_pop_table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    row_list = [ data.text for data in cols ]

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([row_list], columns = ['Zip Code','type','county','Population', 'area_codes'])
    temp_df = temp_df[['Zip Code', 'Population']]
    austin_pop = austin_pop.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop = True)


austin_pop = austin_pop.iloc[1:, :] 
austin_pop['Zip Code'] = austin_pop['Zip Code'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
print (austin_pop)
   Zip Code Population
1     73301          0
2     73344          0
3     78681     50,606
4     78701      6,841
5     78702     21,334
6     78703     19,690
7     78704     42,117
8     78705     31,340
9     78708          0
10    78709          0
11    78710          0
12    78711          0
13    78712        860
14    78713          0
15    78714          0
16    78715          0
17    78716          0
18    78717     22,538
19    78718          0
20    78719      1,764
21    78720          0
22    78721     11,425
23    78722      5,901
24    78723     28,330
25    78724     21,696
26    78725      6,083
27    78726     13,122
28    78727     26,689
29    78728     20,299
30    78729     27,108
..      ...        ...
45    78746     26,928
46    78747     14,808
47    78748     40,651
48    78749     34,449
49    78750     26,814
50    78751     14,385
51    78752     18,064
52    78753     49,301
53    78754     15,036
54    78755          0
55    78756      7,194
56    78757     21,310
57    78758     44,072
58    78759     38,891
59    78760          0
60    78761          0
61    78762          0
62    78763          0
63    78764          0
64    78765          0
65    78766          0
66    78767          0
67    78768          0
68    78772          0
69    78773          0
70    78774          0
71    78778          0
72    78779          0
73    78783          0
74    78799          0

[74 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You made it really easy to follow. The only thing I didn't get was --- row_list = [ data.text for data in cols ]---. It's pretty self explanatory, I've just never seen it before.

Comment: yes. it's called list comprehension. Only really started to use that a few months ago, and I'm glad I did. Essentially turns a for loop into a one-liner. If this worked out for you, make sure to accept the answer.